# run jar file instead of bash in xfce4-terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I've written in very simple shell in java.

now I want xfce4-terminal to run my java shell (myshell.jar) instead of bash when I run xfce4-terminal.

I put below command in xfce4-terminal's preferences, but I get error (screenshot below)

java -jar /home/farhad/Desktop/myshell.jar

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to java?

Comment: @jordanm yes, I put the /usr/bin/java but I got same error